# some SOAP webservices cannot add correctly to webreferences in microsoft visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I'm try to add reference to web service in project webreference in Visual Studio 2017.

I select a web service wsdl file, after which a link to my web service appears in the web references section of the solution explorer in my project

but in object model my object model of my web service is missing

and this missing in visual studio intellisense

Web service wsdl (filename v3_1.wsdl) and all need xsd you can see in attachments

Comment: but in soapUI all working correctly

Comment: attachments can see there [link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/G4wh/CxadpGYuH)